# VMware Workstation player 16 no uninstall option

Tags: vmware, uninstall, vmware-player

I have vmware player and i want to uninstall it. But it does not show up on the control panel. Neither the Settings app. I tried using Glary's utilities but it still did not show up. I searched for a uninstall file in its main location but still nothing. I can't find any way to uninstall it, i searched google only thing i found was the classic way of doing it in the control panel, and thats it nothing else. I went all the way to page five aswell so i don't know what to do

Comment: You say you have VMware Workstation  player installed. See if you have VMware Workstation in Programs and Features. If you have Workstation installed, Player is included and not separate.

Comment: @John On the "Windows turn features on and off"? if so its not there. I checked some other things on Settings but i could not find workstation player.

Comment: I am not sure. Try installing Workstation Pro as a trial. This includes Player. Restart and uninstall Workstation Pro. Restart again. See if Player is now gone.

Comment: @John Even worse. Its problem has doubled now. I have both Vmware workstation pro (free trial) and workstation player on my computer. No possible way to uninstall them

Comment: Try a Windows 10 Repair Install (Microsoft Media Creation Link) and use the option to Keep Everything to begin with .

Answer (score 0):

Found it. After a while of searching related questions i came across somebody that wanted to  uninstall avast.

I saw answer saying to use the setup used to install avast to uninstall it.
So i did the same thing the answer said.